# Div float left: Long divs clearing?

Tags: css, html, css-float

[image: DIV Float]

The problem is that I want the bottom row of orange DIVs to appear where the green ones are. It looks like the long div on the right is clearing left?

All DIVS are floating left, and they need to be floated left (floating right would send them over to the other side of the page).

HTML:

```
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="long"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.small
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.large
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 450px;
  float: left;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any code?  Get a starting point and see what you have done thus far?

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried, preferrably to a site like jsfiddle.com

Comment: can you differientiate with css the too-high orange div from other ? If yes, I would remove him from floating with something like this:  #longDiv {position:absolut;right:0px}

Comment: @Qtax: No actually, it's ones on this one...

Comment: Added the code. They looks yellow to me, but my post was edited so thats cool I guess :S

Answer (score 1):

You could make one div container for all the small boxes and after that container you can put your big box.

```
<div> // big box
  <div> // small box
  </div>
  <div> // small box
  </div>
  <div> // small box
  </div>
</div> // end big box
<div> // long box
</div>
```

This code works for me:
http://codepaste.net/gr59ax

Comment: Thanks, the container for the small boxes idea has worked great! :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>

    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>

    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
<div class="talldiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    /*width should be the total of all the small boxes widths and margins */
    width: 241px;
    float:left;
}

#wrapper div {
    /*all of my divs look like this*/
    margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float:left;
}

.orange {
    background: orange;
}

.green {
    background: #a4e837;
}

.talldiv {
    /*i go outside the wrapper div*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: red;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the container for the small boxes idea has worked great! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate all your squares div in an other div which will be also in float: left:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rect"></div>
```

with the CSS:

```
div.square {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

div.rect {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 226px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

div.group {
    float: left;   
}
```

And the result is: http://jsfiddle.net/4sTPq/

Comment: Thanks, the container for the small boxes idea has worked great! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xPGmR/

As you can see i didn't change so much the css code: I played a bit with `nth-child` pseudoclass and this specific solution requires that large block will be always the fifth-indexed inside your wrapper.

I didn't change the `float` and blocks are the same of your example: I've just positioned the large block in absolute inside a relative positioned wrapper

Please note that `nth-child` is supported from IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-child but, if you need a wider crossbrowsing, maybe you can replace that selector with some complex selectors involving the adjacent sibling selector (or changing the markup)

Comment: Thanks, the container for the small boxes idea has worked great! :)